# Add row to array json with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Example, I get this value by textarea:

- row1:   `<h1> title 1 </h1>`
- row2:   `<h2> title 2 </h2>`

And save in "var cover"

I want add in array json like this:

```
"cover": [
    "<h1> title 1 </h1>","<h2> title 2 </h2>"
]
```

I mean, each row becomes a field of an array json.
I tried:

```
JSON.stringify(cover);
```

but the result was this:

```
"<h1> title 1 </h1>\n<h2> title 2 </h2>"
```

Thanks :D

Comment: can you share how the `var cover` is created

Comment: Do you really want JSON (a string) or an actual JavaScript array? What are you planning to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

```
var myString = "<h1>Title 1</h1>\r\n<h1>Title 2</h1>";
var myObject = myString.split("\r\n");
```

And you will have:

```
["<h1>Title 1</h1>", "<h1>Title 2</h1>"]
```

\r\n is a row break, probably what you'll get out of a text area.

**Edit**
JSON.stringify() is for turning an object to a string so that you could for example send it to a server. JSON.parse() does the opposite. JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObject)) would give you the same code as above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JavaScript split function to create an array.
Take a look to my example.

```js
function getCover() {
  var str = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
  var obj = {cover: str.split("\n")};
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj)
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea">
line1
line2
line3
line4</textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="getCover()">Get Object</button>
<br><br>
Output:<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Line break:
var br = "\r\n";

// Input string:
var str = "<h1> title 1 </h1>" + br
    + "<h2> title 2 </h2>" + br
;

// All rows: [ '<h1> title 1 </h1>', '<h2> title 2 </h2>', '' ]
var all = str.split(br);

// ...or even better: [ '<h1> title 1 </h1>', '<h2> title 2 </h2>' ]
var notEmpty = str.split(br).filter(function(txt){return txt.length;});
```